# How to escape parenthesis in grok that have number in it? For example, (396)

Tags: regex, configuration, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to transfer a example log file to grok regex and couldn't find a way online. How to transfer the log message to grok regex.

I want to transfer something like this "
2019-07-09 13:51:00,146  INFO Thread-89 task.AbstractTaskProcessor(106) messages"
to grok regex

Windows machine. I have try multiple ways to convert the log message to regex but none of them works. The Kibana doens't display the Filed of Loglevel.

```
 grok {
    match => {
       "messgae" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} *%{LOGLEVEL:level} (?<logthread>(?:[()a-zA-Zd-]+[0-9]*)) 
%{JAVACLASS:class} %{NUMBER} %{GREEDYDATA:message} 
    }
  }
```

The Kibana should have loglevel as a field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{NUMBER} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logthread} %{DATA:class}\(%{NUMBER}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I tested it on :

```
2019-07-09 13:51:00,146 INFO Thread-89 task.AbstractTaskProcessor(106) messages
```

you will get the following fields:

```
timestamp   2019-07-09·13:51:00
message     messages
class       task.AbstractTaskProcessor
logthread   Thread-89
level       INFO
```

Comment: Thank you, I use `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} *%{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logthread} %{DATA:class}\(%{NUMBER}\) %{GREEDYDATA:message}`
and the grok debugger is good. But do you know why that I can't have the loglevel display in the kibana? I have logthread and other field display correctly, but the level is not showing up.